# Having issue in get_timeline() function of tweet count

Tags: r, twitter, analysis, tweets

I'm using this code and every run the code import different count tweet.

```
get_timeline("realDonaldTrump", n=500)
```

Example if I run cod import 600 obs. and ı use again then import 400 obs. but I want if I write n=900 then import 900 obs.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For very high volume accounts / accounts with high numbers of requests, this can sometimes be a result of eventual consistency where data centers may not be synchronised at the moment of your request.